# How to get image from imageView?

Tags: android, crop, pinch

I have implemented custom imageView with a pinch option. Now I stuck in after pinch whatever the image visible in imageview. Only get the pinched/visible image as cropped & set that cropped image to another imageview. Pls, help to achieve this.

Comment: Try this link,
https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Comment: yes. But how did they calculate matrix?